# Flask_session in filesystem not saving session data when using Safari but works on every other browser?

Tags: flask, session, redirect, safari

I am creating a flask application that has a login page and when it tries to login and redirect to the target page, the application doesn't save information about the user making the flask_sessions appear as though empty. When the decorator for login required is set off, the session appears empty(as if the user didn't log in at all), and therefore redirects back to the login page. I used chrome and any other browsers and it works, but not safari.

[Code_repo](https://github.com/bolivarc3/Studyist)
the main code is in app.py . A mock piece of code on how the system generally works is below

Any help is appreciated!

I am expecting of the user to login, for it to check if there is the key(username) within the session to verify that the user did log in.

I have tried

- Seeing if the redirections don't work on safari?
  -Applying the SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE to "None"
  -Applying the SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE to "True"
  -Seeing if the decorators were not working
  -Updating Safari

Here is a sample of how my code verifies the login and works

```
#configurations
app = Flask(__name__)
load_dotenv()
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
    aws_access_key_id = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY'),
    aws_secret_access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        )
app.secret_key = os.urandom(100)
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True  # Ensure cookies are only sent over HTTPS
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True  # Prevent client-side JavaScript from accessing cookies
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(minutes=30)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = redis.from_url(os.environ.get('SESSION_REDIS'))
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
Session(app)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False

#packages installed
###
# pip = "*"
#flask = "*"
#flask-session = "*"
#datetime = "*"
#requests = "*"
#botocore = "*"
#boto3 = "*"
#zipfile36 = "*"
#psycopg2 = "*"
#py-bcrypt = "*"
#flask-migrate = "*"
#flask-mail = "*"
#itsdangerous = "*"
#gunicorn = "*"
#python-dotenv = "*"
#oauthlib = "*"
#redis = "*"
#beautifulsoup4 = "*"
# ####

#mock, sample
@app.before_request
def default_login_required():
    login_valid = 'username' in session
    # validates to false because username is not found. Redirects to the login page
    if (request.endpoint and 
        'static' not in request.endpoint and 
        not login_valid and 
        not getattr(app.view_functions[request.endpoint], 'is_public', False) ) :
        flash("Login to Continue with Your Session")
        return redirect(url_for("login_page"))

@app.route("/login_page", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login_page():
    username = "bob"
    session["username"] = username
    return redirect(url_for("homepage"))

@app.route("/homepage", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def homepage():
    #line below returns an error saying that "username" does not exist in the session
    print(session["username"])...
**your text**
```